# Class for Making, Inserting rows and retriving queries

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to imitate one of the code of Collective Intelligence and stumbled due to some unkown error. All the methods works fine inside the class except the one for retrieving query.

```
class Connect:
  # Create the Database
    def __init__(self,dbname):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
  # Add the row
    def create(self,date,name,age):
        self.con.execute('create table Profile(date text, name text,age real)')
  # Lock the changes
    def commit(self):
        self.con.commit()
  # Retrive the details
    def getentry(self,table,field,value):
        cursor = self.con.execute(
                     "select * from %s where %s = '%s'" % (table,field,value))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        print result_set
```

Working Example :

1. To create DB

C = Connect('test.db')

1. To add rows

C.create('2013-03-06','Joy',34)

1. To make changes and lock the files

C.commit()

1. Getting the row

C.getentry(Profile,name,'Joy')

Error : **NameError: name 'Profile' is not defined**

Then with making parenthesis.

C.getentry('Profile','name','Joy')

Result = [  ]

Comment: OP, please provide sample inputs, corresponding outputs, a minimal working code sample, reason why you consider the outputs to be incorrect, steps you have taken to correct the code, and the expected (correct) outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `Connect.create`. It creates the table but does not populate it as the comment above its definition appears to imply. You need to update it to something like the following:

```
def create(self,date,name,age):
    self.con.execute( 'create table Profile(date text, name text,age real)' )
    self.con.execute( "insert into Profile values('{0}','{1}','{2}')"
                      .format(date,name,age) )
    return
```

Comment: @BhupendrasinhThakre, glad to hear that it worked for you. Personally, I find the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/) to be very well written and have never needed to buy a book about Python (so far).